# How do I replace part of a string from one cell from a string in another cell?

Tags: excel

Can someone help me with taking the string from one cell and use it to replace part of a string from another cell?

I have a list of names in column A and a list of messages that use that name in column B. Basically I'm just trying to find "T**-***" and replace it with the name in column A, but I can't seem to find a simple way to do that.

[Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po1ic.png)

Comment: Either write a formula in an unused column to the right and fill down or write some vba to loop through the cells and make the replacements in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"T**-***",A1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]